# SQL server is there recursive reserve word?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any reserve word 'RECURSIVE' while using CTE query. For example,

```
WITH RECURSIVE node_rec AS (
   (SELECT 1 AS depth, ARRAY[node] AS path, *
    FROM   nodes
    WHERE  parent IS NULL
    LIMIT  10
   )    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.depth + 1, r.path || n.node, n.*
    FROM   node_rec r 
    JOIN   nodes    n ON n.parent = r.node
    WHERE  r.depth < 4
)
```

How to achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

Ms Sql recursive CTE syntax has no RECURSIVE keyword See
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx
Ie. CTE of the form

```
WITH cte_name ( column_name [,...n] )
AS
(
–- Anchor member 
UNION ALL
–- Recursive member 
)
```

is recursive when Recursive member references  `cte_name`. For example

```
WITH node_rec AS (
    SELECT TOP(10) 1 AS depth, node AS path, *
    FROM   nodes
    WHERE  parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.depth + 1, r.path +'/'+ n.node, n.*
    FROM   node_rec r 
    JOIN   nodes n ON n.parent = r.node
    WHERE  r.depth < 4
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. It's automatic and would be like this:

```
WITH node_rec AS (
    SELECT TOP 10 1 AS depth, [node] AS path, *
    FROM   nodes
    WHERE  parent IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.depth + 1, path, n.*
    FROM   node_rec r 
    JOIN   nodes    n ON n.parent = r.node
    WHERE  r.depth < 4
)
SELECT *
FROM node_rec
```

I'm not sure what the equivalent of your ARRAY[node] in each select is.